# How to create a tuple of non-copyable objects

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

I'm trying to create a tuple of non-copyable objects. When I have the copy-constructor in-place, I'm able to construct the tuple. When they are deleted, the compilation fails.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A {
    int& x;
    int& y;

    A(int& a, int& b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};

class B {
public:
    B(int& w, int& x, int& y, int& z)
    : a_b_{ A(w,x),A(y,z)} {}
    
private:
    std::tuple<A, A> a_b_;
};

int main() {
    int w =1, x=2, y=3, z=4;
    B b{w,x,y,z};
    return 0;
}
```

I was able to get this to work by adding a tuple constructor.

```
struct A {
    int& x;
    int& y;

    A(int& a, int& b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

    
    template<typename ...Args>
    A(const std::tuple<Args...> &args)
        : A(args, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}) {}

    template<typename ...Args, std::size_t ...Is>
    A(const std::tuple<Args...> &args, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : A(std::get<Is>(args)...) {}


};

class B {
public:
    B(int& w, int& x, int& y, int& z)
    : a_b_{ std::forward_as_tuple(w,x), std::forward_as_tuple(y,z)} {}
    
private:
    std::tuple<A, A> a_b_;
};
```

This is not ideal since it requires adding this constructor to all my classes. Is there any solution which does not require altering the objects in the tuple? Thanks!

Comment: One option is to add a constructor `A(std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<int>, std::reference_wrapper<int>>)`.

Comment: I am failing to understand the point of this. As far as I can follow you can either: (1) Store reference in the tuple and risk dangling references. (2) Move objects into the tuple requiring a move constructor. (3) construct the tuple members in-situ, which is then non-copyable as well. Trying to do what you're doing is seems like a code smell to me, i.e. you're trying to do something you're not supposed to do. Could you perhaps elaborate more on your goal; perhaps I can come up with a solution then ;)

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't make `A` movable? Having a class that is neither copyable neither movable will crate many problems along the way. If you make `A` movable then the code works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in C++17. Doesn't work in C++11/14 as in C++17 RVO is mandated.

It requires an intermediate class `C` that is used to construct `A`. In prior versions to C++17 you'd have to add an additional constructor to `A`.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A {
    int& x;
    int& y;

    A(int& a, int& b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};

struct C {
    int* x;
    int* y;
    
    C(int& a, int& b) : x(&a), y(&b) {};
    
    operator A () const
    {
        return A(*x,*y);
    }
};

class B {
public:
    B(int& w, int& x, int& y, int& z)
    : a_b_{ C{w,x}, C{y,z}} {}
    
private:
    std::tuple<A, A> a_b_;
};

int main() {
    int w =1, x=2, y=3, z=4;
    B b{w,x,y,z};
    return 0;
}
```

If you were to use `std::pair` instead of `std::tuple`, you could achieve it as well via `std::piecewise_construct`. See,

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A {
    int& x;
    int& y;

    A(int& a, int& b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};


class B {
private:
    std::pair<A, A> a_b_;
public:
    B(int& w, int& x, int& y, int& z)
    : a_b_{std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(w,x),  std::forward_as_tuple(y,z)} {}
};

int main() {
    int w =1, x=2, y=3, z=4;
    B b{w,x,y,z};
    return 0;
}
```